# Call function in JS file from Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

What I am trying to do is when index.html sends a message back to the server, I want to call a function in `app.js` called `changeButton()` that will update a header color on index.html.

Here is my node.js file:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var express=require('express');

var tools = require('./assets/js/app.js');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      console.log('message: ' + msg);
      if(msg == "color") {
        socket.emit("changeButton"); //working now
      }
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

app.js is in assets/js folder.

```
function getMessage() {
    $('form').unbind('submit').bind('submit', function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });
}

function changeButton() {
  $('#status').css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Here is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- app.js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- app.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="status"> Node Test </h1>

    <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <form action="">
            <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button onclick="getMessage();">Send</button>
        </form>

    <script>
        var socket = io();
        socket.on("changeButton", changeButton);
    </script>
</body>
```

WORKING NOW!
THANKS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is changeButton defined?  If it is defined in index.html, then you'll need to do something like:

```
if (msg == "add") {
  socket.emit("changeButton")
}
```

and on the client side:

```
socket.on("changeButton", changeButton);
```

Comment: I edited the question a little.  changeButton is defined in app.js.  I imported the code via @joemfb answer.  jQuery is not defined now, which I believe is probably the wrong was to go about doing this.  Loading jQuery on the server.

Comment: Ok cool.

If you want to change the color of an element, then the Javascript must have access to the HTML element.  If the HTML element is in index.html, then you will need to run the Javascript on the client side.  

You can still use sockets to control this however, like in my answer.  Once you get a message "color", simply emit back to the client an event that will execute changeButton (which must be defined in the index.html scope).  Does that make sense?  I could be misunderstanding what you want to accomplish.

Comment: This makes sense, kinda.  Ill update the question with all the code

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: while this answer is technically correct with regards to importing server-side JS libraries, that appears not to be the problem you need solved. @tony-nardi has explained how you can emit a server-side event over a websocket connection, and react to it client-side. You should do that, and import app.js into your index.html.

You need to import the code where `changeButton()` is defined:

```
var lib = require('assets/app.js')
```

And then reference that variable when invoking the function:

```
lib.changeButton()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Im mixing my questions up, sorry!